# az cli query preserve column order

Tags: azure

```bash
az network vnet list \
    --query '[].{"Region": location, "vNet": name, "CIDR": addressSpace.addressPrefixes[0], "vNet Id": id}' \
    --output json
```

I get different column output order than that of the query e.g:

```json
  {
    "CIDR": "10.240.0.0/16",
    "Region": "westeurope",
    "vNet": "my-vnet",
    "vNet Id": "/subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/my-rg/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli) , we can display Azure CLI in many Output formats

- If the Output format is  ***`json`*** , then the output is displayed in Alphabetical order by default
- If you want to get the order which you have specified in the query list, use the ***table*** or ***tsv***  format

***Output format for table***
[image]

***Output format for tsv (Tab-separated values)***
[image]